# How do I render objects as 'icons' in three.js?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Say I have a nice spaceship rendered in my scene. I then zoom out and the ship becomes smaller. This is all quite simple to achieve. Now at some point I want to replace the spaceship object with a simple triangle representing the ship. At this stage the icon for the ship should be rendered instead of the ship. Obviously the triangle should move based on the ship's movement and my camera movements. The triangle should not change orientation, so even if I rotate the camera or have the ship roll the triangle should stay the same orientation. So on a canvas this would be very simple to do. I would just take the x and y components of the 3d object and draw my triangle at the coordinates. My problem is that I do not know how to draw on the WebGL canvas directly? Is it possible? If not do anybody have any pointers to strategies to get this done? I would be happy if I could get nudged in the right direction :) Thanks in advance.

Update : What I eventually decided to do was to use the orthographic camera overlay approach suggested below and in a couple of other places.

Comment: Your best strategy would be to rasterize your icon into a texture then map your texture onto either a plane or a box.

Comment: @Aron. Thanks. I have thought of this but that creates the difficulty of placing the plane or box somwhere in the scene in such a fashion as to keep its size the same relative to my camera. Projecting the 'icon' onto a sphere might work, but then my guess is that I will be losing some definition due to the texture mapping ....

Comment: How would that be harder than using Canvas? Your icon doesn't need to be at the same depth as your ship (most people don't own 3D monitors yet).

Comment: Use a sprite and an orthographic overlay as in http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_sprites.html. You are just going to have to calculate the screen coordinates of your ship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Sprite object for icon. Then place icon right between spaceship and camera in a specific distance from the camera (using Raycaster or just calculation).

Use of orthographic overlay as mentioned by @WestLangley is also possible. Since you would have to calculate ship's position relative to your canvas in this case, maybe you could even create pure HTML overlay using DIV and place your icon in it as IMG object.

Comment: I do not like the idea of using pure HTML overlays. It seems like they are very optimised and they are offloaded to the GPU if available, but I still don't like the idea ...

Comment: My biggest issue with the sprite placement idea is that on every frame the new position for the sprite needs to be calculated from scratch since both the camera and the object for which the icon is intended is moving. If I were to have many objects for which this needs to be done  performance could be impacted quite badly.

Comment: I guess this applies to all solutions. Since your camera and spaceship are moving, so has the icon. No matter what solution you'll choose. Or not?

Comment: Yip thats basically the conclusion that I cam to too.

Comment: I've chosen this as the answer since the I decided to go the Othographic camera view approach and to just calculate the icon position. SO far it looks like it holds up quite nicely under load ...

Comment: In this case, credit should go to @WestLangley for proposing that first.

Comment: If there is another spaceship between camera and the distant ship/icon - do you want icon to be shadowed by this ship? Because when using overlay, icon will be always visible no matter what.